# how to add dot symbol after nth character of string in c#

Tags: c#

how to add a decimal symbol after second character of a string.

sample data = 78383083

desired op = 78.383083

code

```
  string data = "011F03010A366B04AC07EB";
    string longitude = data.Substring(14, data.Length - 14); //04AC07EB
    string latitude = data.Substring(6, data.Length - 14); //010A366B
    long lat=Convert.ToInt64(longitude, 16);//78383083 
    string latvalue=lat.ToString();
    // string latvalue1=latvalue.Substr(0,2)+":"+latvalue.substr(2);
```

Comment: I suppose you could cast it to an `int` and do a `.ToString("N2")`.

Comment: you commented-out last line was almost there. Only the function is `Substring`. or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: oh thanks , my code is working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the insert() method in C# to insert character in any position. Remember it is a zero based index.

```
string final_data = data.Insert(2,".");
```

You can learn more about [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple:

```
string result = data.Insert(2, ".");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
string str = "123456789";

           if (str.Length > 5)
           {
             label1.Text = string.Concat(str.Substring(0, 5), "...");
           }
           else
           {
               label1.Text = str;
           }
```